# Phrase usage: As a result

Tags: grammar, phrases

As far as what I've learned, this is how you use the phrase "as a result".
e.g. He was late, as a result, he didn't catch the bus.
   = He was late***,*** he didn't catch the bus as a result.

I would like to know whether you need "and" as a conjunction with phrases like this.

---He was late, and as a result, he didn't catch the bus. (correct?)
  ---He was late***, and*** he didn't catch the bus as a result. (correct?)
  ---He was late. He didn't catch the bus as a result. (correct?)

How do I know whether I need conjunctions when dealing with phrases like this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "and" if you're yoking two clauses each of which can stand independently.

**He was late.**

That is a short but perfectly complete sentence.

**As a result, he didn't catch the bus.**

Although it refers back to a prior statement, that is also an independent sentence.

Your choices when writing are to use "and" between them, or to use a semicolon:

**He was late and as a result he didn't catch the bus.**
**He was late; as a result he didn't catch the bus.**

A separate question is whether a comma is expected before and/or after "as a result".

A comma is usually placed after such a phrase. With the semicolon yoking the two independent clauses, it's simple:

**He was late; as a result, he didn't catch the bus.**

But how to punctuate when using "and"?

It is important to note that these are *conventions*, and not part of the language itself; when speaking we use syntactic pauses and intonation patterns to indicate where clauses begin and end.

You will probably find in the wild both forms below:

**He was late, and as a result, he didn't catch the bus.**

**He was late and, as a result, he didn't catch the bus.**

Comment: I see that your answer and mine are slightly different. Let's see what comments we both get. It seems I am more minimalistic about commas.

Comment: I've seen on several textbooks saying "He was late and as a result he didn't catch the bus. He was late; as a result he didn't catch the bus." but also some dictionaries saying "He was late, as a result, he didn't catch the bus."  Here I want to share a point of how my teacher taught me about this. We learned several words like " thus" and "whereas". I was taught that when connecting two clauses, adverbs like "thus" need and; however, whereas, being a conjunction itself, doesn't need another "and".

Answer (score 2):

> He was late, as a result, he didn't catch the bus.

My suggestions

He was late. As a result he didn't catch the bus.

He was late; he didn't catch the bus.

He was late: as a result he didn't catch the bus.

He was late and didn't catch the bus.

You might like to consult the article [Using the semi-colon and colon](http://www2.le.ac.uk/offices/ld/resources/writing/grammar/grammar-guides/semicolon) from the Universtiy of Leicester.

Comment: the semi-colon and colon part was perfect. As for my countries English education, they made no effort to teach this. what a fail